# How would I declare a variable with a "+" or "-" sign in it? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a program in Javascript but I am not sure how to declare a variable for grades with + and - in them.

```
    var A+ = 4.0;
    var A = 4.0;
    var A- = 3.67;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are illegal characters in variable names, but even if they weren't, this sounds like the perfect place for an *object* (a single variable), rather than multiple standalone variables, and the object can have the key-value pairs you're interested in:

```
const grades = {
  'A+': 4,
  'A': 4,
  'A-': 3.67,
  // ...
};
```

(Note that *numbers* with trailing decimal zeros have their trailing zeros truncated automatically - if you want to use `4.0`, either use a string `'4.0'` instead, or use `toFixed` later, when retrieving the number, to convert to a string)

To iterate over such an object, use `Object.entries` to get each key-value pair:

```
Object.entries(grades).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  // on first iteration, key will be A+, value will be 4
});
```

and to access or set properties on it, put the key names in brackets:

```
grades['A+'] = 'newA+Value';
```

(dot notation, such as `grades.A`, only works when the key follows the same rules as valid variable names - otherwise, have to use bracket notation)

Comment: When attempting to use Object.entries, I get the same issue I had trying to declare the variables originally. It will not read it as "A+", separating the + from the A.

Comment: In the first iteration of `Object.entries`, the key will be a string containing `A+`, for example, which is perfectly valid - then, just use that string (and its value) for whatever you need it for.

Comment: Okay, thank you. My last question would be how would I use this in a function, for example, if I used document.getElementById("grade1").value to get the inputted value from the textarea, say it was an A+. Would setting up these constants automatically turn that input into 4? Sorry for the confusion, I am just starting out with programming.

Comment: See the last part of the answer - to access or set properties on the object, just put the key names in brackets. eg if `value` contains the `A+` string, then you can get the number by doing `grades[value]`